# Is there a name for this: an even cycle having two smaller even cycles inscribed, linking bipartitions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My apologies for the horribly worded title, I'm not sure how to describe this.

Learning about bipartite graphs in discrete math and I noticed this when testing a few cycle graphs. For $n$ even, $C_n$ can have two graphs $C_{n/2}$ inscribed within, which connect the two bipartitioned sets.

[See examples here for $C_6$, $C_8$, and $C_{10}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWuKP.jpg). (the last one is hard to see, but it does have two pentagons inscribed within it) So $C_6$ has a $C_3$ that connects the nodes of one of its bipartitioned sets, and another $C_3$ connecting the nodes in the other set.

Is there a name for this property/feature/whatever?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what property/feature you are referring to.  As you have noted, the even cycle $C_{2k}$ is bipartite, which each part being an independent set of size $k$.  Hence you could fit a cycle $C_k$ into each part, but you could also fit any graph on $k$ vertices into each part.

Comment: @Shagnik thanks for the feedback, I just wasn't sure how to word the question. I was focusing on cycles specifically and it just seemed interesting that we can nest a cycle of exactly half size, so I was looking for some deeper connection. Which is obvious now that I look back on it, because that is just constructing a cycle for each partition, of which there are two.